# Multiple simultaneously MultiTouchGesture Events in Flash (AIR)

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, air

I have created an AIR application that makes use of Flash' build in capability of taking multi touch gestures
(`TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM` & `TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ROTATE`)

It works fine on my Mac using the computers trackpad. It also works fine on a Windows 7 machine with a touchscreen attached.

But I can only modify one object at a time. Is that a limitation in Flash or is it possible to modify more objects at the same time and that way possible to make a multi-user multi-touch application?

Answer (score 0):

you can query the numer of supporte touch points on a device:

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;
trace(Multitouch.maxTouchPoints);
```

Mac OS X doesn't support touch events in AIR, only gestures in AIR 2.0+ application, so the above code will return `0` on a Mac, even on MacBooks with touch-enabled trackpads.

Windows 7 with touch-enabled hardware supports touch events, both in web browsers and AIR applications.  and, of course, Android and other mobile  devices also support touch events.

read more here:  http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/multitouch_gestures.html

Comment: Hey, thanks. I do not have access to the touchscreen at the moment but will try it out to see how many points it returns (I was told it should be a lot).

Answer (score 0):

Due to this article there's issues related to the zoom and rotate gestures on at least Windows 7. As it points out that the user will have to remove fingers from screen between performing gestures. That is exactly what I experienced!

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS1ca064e08d7aa930-581fb7b1257b16ff45-8000.html#WS4cba193aad476e9f-61be7a7c12633893a55-8000

Though this do not answer my question exactly since there might be other ways to take gestures simultaneously....